# Is $ \{ n a_n \}_n $ decreasing sequence, where is $ \{ a_n \}_{n} $ monotonically decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose  $ \{ \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \}_{n} $ is monotonically decreasing sequence and $ \{ n \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} \}_{n} $  converges to a real number k, How can i prove $ \{ n \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} \}_{n} $  is decreasing sequence?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: By decreasing you mean strictly decreasing or no increasing? If it is the first then it is not true, take $a_n=1/n$.

Comment: Why do you think it is true?

Comment: It's not true.  Consider $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: @aTree Looks like an answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews , it was used in a published paper, i'm struggling with it and we know $ \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} $ converges to zero

Comment: Given any monotonically decreasing $b_n\to 0$ we can define $a_1=1, a_{n+1}=a_nb_n.$ Then $$a_{n+1}/a_{n}=b_n.$$ So your sequences really includes all monotonic decreasing functions. And the counterexamples given for your original question still apply.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample:

Note that $(na_{n})_{n}$ is bounded, then is necesary
\begin{equation*}
   na_{n}\to k\Rightarrow \frac{na_{n}}{n} = a_{n} \to 0
\end{equation*}

As $(a_{n})_{n}$ it is decreasing, for all $n\geq N$, $a_{n}\geq0$, considering (a candidate):
$$
a_{n} = \frac{1}{n+1}\to 0
$$
then $(na_{n})_{n}$ is growing,

$$
\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)_{n}=\left(\frac{1}{2} , \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{5},\dots\right)
$$
as
$\frac{n}{n+1}\leq\frac{n+1}{n+2}\Leftrightarrow n^{2}+2n = n(n+2)\leq(n+1)^{2} = n^{2}+2n+1$.
And
$$
\frac{n}{n+1}\to1=k
$$

The intuition behind is that you multiply a decreasing sequence that converges to zero (this sequence is $(a_{n})_{n}$) with an increasing and divergent monotone sequence (this sequence is $(n)_{n}$, this product turns out to be hardly decreasing unless the decreasing sequence is stronger than the sequence $(n)_{n}$

Comment: yes, you are true something similar of this is used in an articel, can i have your email to send you that article please???

Comment: Yes, mi mail is manuel.torres@ug.uchile.cl

Comment: thank you, and sorry i asked in bad way now i edit that,